# How do you use the **kwargs argument in mpmath.findroot?

Tags: python, mpmath

I am trying to find the roots of a function that has a lot of arguments using `findroot` in `mpmath`, but in this question, I am going to use a simple function.

```
from mpmath import mp


def func(x, **parameters):

 return parameters["a"]*x*x + 1
   

solution = mp.findroot(f = func, x0 = 0.955j, solver = 'muller', **kwargs = (a = 1))
```

Output:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The `func` function in the code returns the value of $f(x) = ax^2 + 1$ at an $x$-value, given the value of $a$. For example, the value of $f(1)$ for $a = 1$ is 2. To find the roots of $f$, I used `findroot`. Since my function has arguments, I will need to use the ***kwargs* in `findroot`. However, I am struggling to use it. I keep on getting a syntax error.

Comment: Just a heads up, LaTeX doesn't render on Stack Overflow unfortunately.

Comment: `**kwargs**` is just short hand for the other optional arguments after `verbose`.  `verify`, `solver`, etc.  See the `arguments` list for https://mpmath.org/doc/current/calculus/optimization.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The syntax error

The syntax error is in assigning `**kwargs =` . The variable `kwargs` is a dictionary, and `**` unpacks that dictionary. The expression `**kwargs = (a = 1)` is essentially trying to unpack a dictionary while also assigning that dictionary *to another variable assignment*.

### Keyword arguments

The `**kwargs` parameter of a function allows you to pass any number of additional keyword arguments. The parameter `a=1` *is* a keyword argument. The `kwargs` itself is a collection of keyword arguments that you want to "package together".

A quick demonstration:

```py
In [1]: def print_kwargs(**kwargs):
   ...:     for key, value in kwargs.items():
   ...:         print(key, value)
   ...:

In [2]: print_kwargs(a=1, b=2, c=3)
a 1
b 2
c 3

In [3]: params = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)

In [4]: print_kwargs(**params)
a 1
b 2
c 3
```

### The actual problem

Looking at the documentation, it looks like the *solver* is allowed to accept whatever `kwargs` you pass. In other words, the `kwargs` ***aren't passed to your function,*** `func`, they're passed to the solver, `'muller'` in your case.

The docs suck and the `kwargs` that the `mpmath.calculus.optimization.Muller` takes aren't explained at all as far as I can see so I have no idea what it does with its keyword arguments, but the point is that the `kwargs` aren't being passed to your function as you expected.

Unfortunately you'll need to do a bit more work on your function `func` if you want it to be a dynamic polynomial which can take arguments for its parameters.

### The solution

Here's what you can do:

```py
def function_builder(**params):
    def func(x):
        return params["a"] * x**2 + 1  # or whatever function
    return func
```

And then you'd do:

```py
>>> params = dict(a=1)
>>> func = function_builder(**params)
>>> mp.findroot(f=func, x0=0.955j, solver='muller')
mpc(real='0.0', imag='1.0')
```

You can implement `function_builder()` in such a way as to *return a new function object* which is only a function of `x`. Then when you want to find the roots of a particular polynomial, you can call `function_builder()` with whatever parameters you want and it'll return the function you want to which `mp.findroot` can then use.

### Notes

Here's an example of how you might implement a general quadratic equation builder:

```py
def quadratic_builder(**params):
    a, b, c = params["a"], params["b"], params["c"]
    def f(x):
        return a * x**2 + b * x + c
    return f
```

Of course, for something as specific as a quadratic equation, it'd be better to explicitly call out the keyword arguments:

```py
def quadratic_builder(*, a, b, c):
    def f(x):
        return a * x**2 + b * x + c
    return f
```

And then you can package together "sets" of coefficients:

```py
coefs_1 = dict(a=1, b=3, c=-5)
coefs_2 = dict(a=-2, b=1, c=0)
coefs_3 = dict(a=-6, b=8, c=3)

f1 = quadratic_builder(**coefs_1)
f2 = quardatic_builder(**coefs_2)
f3 = quardatic_builder(**coefs_3)
```

Etc.